# Saving an item as "Favorite" and showing it across other recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have 1 viewpager with 2 pages main, favorites. Both have RecyclerViews, with endless scrolls, after 15 items it loads another 15 from server and so on. I want to implement an option to add an item from recyclerView to favorite and refresh both recyclerViews. I can add them to favorite or remove them if they are added. I already have this implemented and it works, perfectly.

The problem is, that if I add item to favorite, it won't refresh other RecyclerView. I had an idea, that for each time I add or remove from favorites, the other fragment restarts, so it request another query from server and you just load them in recycler view. It worked, but you were always put on the top, which is not a good UX. You can open item and get more information about that item, and you can add them to favorites inside that activity. So when i returned from that activity everything stayed the same, like you didn't add them to favorites. But actually you did.

I don't know how to solve this problem :/ other asking another query from server, and loading it inside of RecylerView. If i didn't had the endless scroll implemented i could probably share the items on both sides, but I have to have endless scroll, too much of data would be wasted.

This is how my Adapter for RecyclerView looks like:

```
        customViewHolder.llLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String fontAwesomeFullHeart = mContext.getString(R.string.fa_heart);
            final String getLikeText = customViewHolder.tvPicLike.getText().toString();
            if (getLikeText == fontAwesomeFullHeart) {
                MyFunctions.showNotToFavoriteHeart(mContext, customViewHolder.tvPicLike, customViewHolder.tvLike);
                API_Network_Service.serverRemoveFromFavorites(mContext, feedItem.getId(), logged_in, customViewHolder.tvPicLike);
            } else {
                MyFunctions.showFavoriteHeart(mContext, customViewHolder.tvPicLike, customViewHolder.tvLike);
                API_Network_Service.serverAddToFavorites(mContext, feedItem.getId(), logged_in, customViewHolder.tvPicLike);
            }
        }
    });
```

And this is from API_SERVICE_CLASS:

```
   public static void serverAddToFavorites(final Context mContext, String apartment_id, RealmUser_Personal user, final TextView tvLike) {
    String user_id = user.getId();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("user_id", user_id);
    HashMap<String, Object> mapMeta = new HashMap<>();
    mapMeta.put("meta", map);
    mapMeta.put("entry_id", apartment_id);
    final ApiUporabnik apiService = ApiClient.getAPIUser().create(ApiUporabnik.class);
    Call<FavoriteAdd> saveFavorite = apiService.favoriteAdd(API_KEY, mapMeta);
    saveFavorite.enqueue(new Callback<FavoriteAdd>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FavoriteAdd> call, Response<FavoriteAdd> response) {
            Log.d("Saved FAV", "");
            //TODO Refresh item everywhere
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FavoriteAdd> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("E: Failed FAV", t.toString());
            tvLike.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.fa_heart_o));
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas, advice, solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I do following steps:

1- Create a database which holds `Id's` of favorite items.

2- In your Main page `adapter` check is added to database or not with something like this:

```
database.isFavoriteItems(Your_Items_ID);
```

3- When click on favorite `Button`, if **Not** exist in `Database` then add new Item to `Database` and if previously added remove it.

```
if(database.isFavoriteItem(Your_Items_ID)){
 database.addToFavorite(Your_Items_ID);
} else {
 database.removeFromFavorite(Your_Items_ID);
}
```

4- When you scroll to favorite list in your fragment call `notifyDataSetChanged` inside:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

5- Also make your database **Singleton** really recommended.

With these steps your problem will be fixed.

Comment: This seems like a smart solution. But the problem is, that I have 2 queries to server. 1. is for Home, and 2. for Favorite. So when Home is loaded i do nothing... And when Favorites load i add all of them, to the database, then i just check if button addFav clicked, then you send to Server and save to Database. This is what i understand from your solution, but how do I then add that item to Favorite fragment or remove them?       
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` would just refresh the feedlist. But there are 2 feedlists 1 for Home and 1 for Favs. If you get what am i saying? :)

Comment: @WinterChilly Call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your Favorite fragment.

Comment: Inside your favorite Adapter your singleton database done exactly what you want :)

Comment: because just one instance of database exist by notifyDataSetChange whole adapter refreshed and new Items from your database added to your list.

Comment: I'll try that out. But i still don't get it... You get a 2 responses and just load them to recyclerview. I get this. Then whatever is Favorite i add them in Database. Still get it... When user presses add to favorite, you add them to server and to database. Database has nothing to do with the favorites. Hmm what about if i save every item that is favorite to the database, and i don't load directly from the response, but from the database, and i'm working with that. I would need favorite list only to add them to Database. This could actually work. Thoughts?

Comment: I exactly try to say these : "what about if i save every item that is favorite to the database"

Comment: Yeah sorry :/, thanks for the help... Let me just test it ^^. Then i'll set your answer as correct one ;).

Comment: I managed somehow to get it to work... but that setUserVisibleHint only works if i scroll, then it changes else it doesn't change :(

Comment: Fixed it ^^, onResume method and there adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but still the FragmentFavs doesn't work, if I add a Favorite it doesn't get added to FragmentFavs

Comment: Fixed the problem, on setUserVisibleHint, I added a function called updatePage, which checked current state of database and previous, not the same, fill it with new ones.